# Extracting data from generator object

Tags: python, pandas, generator

Use several CSV files to create data frame that I want to filter with several pandas `.asfreq()` options, create generator object, sort and list top results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

N = 100
dates = pd.date_range('19971002', periods=N, freq='B')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates),1),index=dates,columns=list('A'))
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates),1),index=dates,columns=list('B'))
pieces = (df, df1)
data = pd.concat((pieces), join='outer', axis = 1)
df['custIndex'] = (df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).cumcount()+1)   # 'CI' =  custIndex increments by 1 for each occurance since month inception

data.head()

time_sets = ['W-Mon', 'W-Tue']
for time_set in time_sets:
    grouped = data.asfreq(time_set).groupby(df.custIndex).sum()
    print time_set
    print grouped.head()


W-Mon
              A         B
custIndex                    
1          1.827512 -0.487051
3         -0.463776 -0.002071
6          2.074173 -0.232500
8         -0.282901  0.575820
11         0.505265 -3.844740
W-Tue
              A         B
custIndex                    
2          1.347802 -0.738638
4          0.273424  0.218833
7          1.439177  3.671049
9          1.722703 -0.962877
12        -3.415453  1.123824
```

Here's where I get in trouble, goal is to sort values column 'A' and 'B' (top values first), and extract custIndex with highest values, and list custIndex, value and column.

```
t = (group.sort_index(by='',ascending=True)for key, group in grouped)
```

Need help with what to sort by, tried `several('CI', 'key')` things without luck.

```
t
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000AA9A318>

top = pd.DataFrame()

for line in t:
top = top.append(line)

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Goal would look like:

```
custIndex   value     time_set  Column
6           2.074173  W_MON     A
1           1.827512  W-MON     A
9           1.722703  W-TUE     B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your generator expression to work, you need to amend it as follows:

```
t = (group.sort_index(ascending=True) for key, group in grouped.iteritems())
```

Even though it may 'work', it may still not do what you are intending.  To see the output, you can try:

```
for line in t:
    print line
```

For a proposed solution, how about:

```
top_n = 5  # The number of top items returned.
goal = pd.DataFrame([[None] * 4] * top_n,  # 4 = number of columns
                    columns=['custIndex', 'value', 'time_set', 'Column'])
for time_set in time_sets:
    grouped = data.asfreq(time_set).groupby(df.custIndex).sum()
    t = (group for group in grouped.unstack().iteritems())
    for [column, custIndex], val in t:
        if val > min(goal.value):
            # Append item to end of goal DataFrame and then re-sort.
            goal.iloc[-1] = [custIndex, val, time_set, column]
            goal.sort('value', ascending=False, inplace=True)

goal.set_index(['custIndex', 'time_set', 'Column'], inplace=True)

>>> goal
                          value
custIndex time_set Column          
12        W-Tue    B       3.048822
5         W-Fri    A        2.63997
18        W-Wed    B       2.570899
10        W-Wed    B       2.493457
19        W-Thu    B       2.164974
```

Comment: Wow!   Thank you, well over my pay grade, but exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for response and for helping me get to next level of pyhton, great stuff!  thank you!